# Javascript string scanner?

Tags: javascript, string, lexical-analysis

I'm wondering, is there any way to scan a string in javascript.

e.g, I've got a string `abcdefdfdfssdfdssdffdq="HELLO"fdndkjdsnkjdnlkdfns` I'd like to scan that string and delete the characters between q=" and " and replace it with `GOODBYE` is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)`
As in: `"abcdefdfdfssdfdssdffdq=\"HELLO\"fdndkjdsnkjdnlkdfns".replace(/".+"/, "\"GOODBYE\"")`

Comment: But, what if I don't know what the word within `q=""` is?

Comment: Edited the code. If you are not familiar with them, I would suggest you spent a little time reading about regular expressions.